# .FromFile underlined red and showing error

Tags: c#

i want to create a windows form which takes image from file and displays in the pictureBox in c#
i am having problem when i type image.FromFile after "=" the FromFile gets red underline as if it does not consists in the library.

```
1 using System;
2 using System.Collections.Generic;
3 using System.ComponentModel;
4 using System.Data;
5 using System.Drawing;
6 using System.Linq;
7 using System.Text;
8 using System.Windows.Forms;
9 using System.IO;
10
11 namespace demo2
12 {
13     public partial class Image : Form
14     {
15        public Image()
16         {
17             InitializeComponent();
18         }
19 
20         
21 
22         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
23         {
24             OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
25             ofd.Filter = "image files|*.png;*.jpg;*.gif";
26             DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
27 
28             if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
29                 return;
30 
31             pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
32             textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
33         }
34                         
35     }
36 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your class is called `Image`, which is in collision with system defined `Image` you want to use. So when you try to use `Image.FromFile`, compiler uses that one defined in your namespace (in your own class) and there's no `FromFile` method defined.

So when you want to use correct `Image` class:

1) you should qualify the namespace like: `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile`

or

2) you can rename your own class to something different from `Image`, so you have no collision in name

Comment: can you please edit the code for me or tell me the line wherei have to change the code.

Comment: line 31: `pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);`

Comment: i am trying to mark but it says mark it after 5 mins....
dont worry i will mark it...well thanks again..

Comment: i wanted to ask that why did this used to give me error when i just typed Image.FromFile?

Comment: because your class has same name `Image`, so compiler uses this class by default, when you try using Image.FromFile (because in same namespace) and there is no such method defined in your class. so when you write full namespace `System.Drawing.Image`, compiler knows, which class you want to use.